# Extract frames from video played on jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

I want to extract frames from video that is being played on jwplayer. I am live streaming the video from my android device to wowza media engine which uses jwplayer to play the video. I want to extract frames of video and save the frames. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

JW Player does not include any ability to manipulate the video in any way, including extracting frames from it. It's just a steering script that passes the video to the browser in a consistent fashion, using either the browser's own HTML5 capabilities or calling upon the Flash player to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: So, there is no way I can extract frames from a live video stream? @MisterNeutron

Comment: Other than the obvious answer - taking screenshots - I wouldn't know about that. But JW Player certainly doesn't give you any way of doing so.

Comment: Indeed, the player does not have a way to do this, it just plays back the media, it doesn't extract frames.